# Why don't I receive notifications on Scifi & Fantasy Meta?

Tags: support, meta, notifications

I would like to know why we don't receive notifications in Scifi & Fantasy Meta when someone...

1. Comments on your question [Sometimes it doesn't work for me - is this a bug?]
2. Replies to your comment
3. Or includes your @username on something

Is there a reason for this and should we have this? I think notifications are really good and we should have this implemented, as when I am commenting on something and someone replies to my comment, I don't receive any kind of warning whatsoever, even when the user uses my @username.

Comment: Calling @MiharuDante, testing testing!

Comment: That works @Pureferret. But everything else doesn't.

Comment: I receive notifications for all of those, with the exception being using @username, which only works if you've already commented in a comment thread (you can't pull someone who hasn't participated in that comment discussion).  As such, I think this should be tagged as "bug" rather than "feature-request".

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro]?

Answer (score 1):

For testing/confirmation:  Miharu, comment on this answer so someone can @ reply to you without commenting on the question.